# Combining two infrance graph tensorflow mobilnetssd v2

Tags: tensorflow

I have trained two object detection models on tensorflow ,

1. the first is an ssd-mobilnetv2 which detects hand gestures,
2. and the second which detects mechanical objects
   my question is :
   how I can use the two models on the same input (the camera) at the same time.
   to be clearer how from the same input I can tell the bounding box of the first inference graph for the gestures (ssd-mobilnet v2)
   and the second inference graph for the mechanical object.

and if there are solutions to put (combining) two inference graph in a single inference graph .

thank you.

Comment: Please add code snippets showing how you use these models one-by-one and also information about your tensorflow version.

Comment: I want to thank you first;
I used this config file: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config.

My version of tensorflow is1.5.

Comment: the code to use the detection on the camera:
https://notebooks.azure.com/ashok-mani/projects/tensor/html/Object_detection_video.py